# mysql joins using having clause

Tags: mysql, join, having

These are tables:

```
mysql> select * from professor;
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
|     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
|     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
|     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
|     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
|     7 | George |      0 |   1500 |   46 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from works;
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
|        2 |     3 |      10 |
|        2 |     1 |       7 |
|        2 |     4 |       6 |
|        2 |     5 |       2 |
|        4 |     2 |       6 |
+----------+-------+---------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+----------+------------+--------+
| courseid | coursename | points |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | Maths      |    100 |
|        2 | Science    |     80 |
|        3 | English    |     85 |
|        4 | Social     |     90 |
|        5 | Malayalam  |     99 |
|        6 | Arts       |     40 |
|        7 | Biology    |    100 |
+----------+------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The question is :

> Return those courses that have been taught by at least 5 different
>   employees

My query is :

```
select course.coursename from course
inner join works
on course.courseid=works.courseid
group by works.empid
having count(empid)>=5;
```

I am supposed to 'Science' as the result. But I get 0 results. Pls help .

Comment: Why are you grouping by empid? The empids are what you want to count, for each _course_ – so that’s what you should group by.

Comment: thank you :) I just realized that just a moment back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select course.coursename from course
inner join works
on course.courseid=works.courseid
group by course.coursename
having count(Distinct(works.empid))>=5;
```

Comment: This should do it but you probably want to add a DISTINCT to the COUNT